# Как правильно перегрузить оператор ввода?

Tags: c++

В простом классе необходимо перегрузить оператор ввода. По непонятной, для меня, причине выдаёт ошибку :"Ошибка (активно)   E0349   отсутствует оператор ">>", соответствующий этим операндам, типы операндов: std::istream >> Shape::Color"
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Shape.h

```
class Shape
{
public:

    enum Color { Red, Black, Green, Blue };

protected:

    Color color;

public:
    virtual Shape* Make()const = 0;
    virtual void Print();

    Shape(Color color);// конструктор с одним параметром
    Shape(const Shape& other);// конструктор крпирования
    
    virtual~Shape();

    void Set_Color(int x); // присваим значение 
    virtual int Get();     // принимаем значение 
    virtual int Square();  // площадь фигуры

    void printMyShape();   // распичатываем

    virtual Shape& operator = (const Shape& other);
    virtual bool operator == (const Shape& other)const;
    bool operator != (const Shape& other);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Shape& an);
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& os, Shape& nov);
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const Shape& an);
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& os, Shape& nov);
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include"Shape.h"

void Shape::Print()
{
    std::cout << this->color << std::endl;
}

Shape::Shape(Color color)
{
    this->color = color;
}

Shape::Shape(const Shape& other)
{
    color = other.color;
}

Shape::~Shape()
{
    std::cout << "Now I am in Shape's destructor!" << std::endl;
}

void Shape::Set_Color(int x)
{
    this->color = static_cast<Color>(x);
}

int Shape::Get()
{
    return this->color;
}

int Shape::Square()
{
    return 0;
}

void Shape::printMyShape()
{
    std::cout << this->color << std::endl;
}

Shape& Shape::operator = (const Shape& other)

{
    this->color = other.color;
    return *this;
}

bool Shape::operator == (const Shape& other)const
{
    return this->color == other.color;
}

bool Shape::operator!=(const Shape& other)
{
    return !(this->color == other.color);
}



//bool Shape::operator==(const Shape* other)
//{
//  if (typeid(*other) == typeid(Circle))
//  {
//      return static_cast<const Circle&>(*other)==*this;
//  }
//  else
//  {
//        return false;
//  }
//}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Shape& an)
{
    os << an.color;
    
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& os, Shape& nov)
{
    os >> nov.color;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: ¿Почему по непонятной? Реализация перегрузки для оператора std::istream >> Shape::Color отсутствует, ее тоже нужно написать.

Comment: Но я ведь и реализую перегрузку для Shape?????

Comment: Разве оператор ввода не перегружен уже в заголовочном файле <istream>???

Comment: В том-то и дело, что реализуете перегрузку только для Shape, а надо еще и для Shape::Color. В библиотеке нет перегрузок для енумераторов.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Теперь разобрался!!!!

Comment: можно  os >> static_cast<int>( nov.color);